# Xamarin.Android type swizzling

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, classloader, xamarin.forms, nineoldandroids

Has anyone been able to get Xamarin.Forms to work on API levels pre-11? `ValueAnimator` doesn't exist, and although this is provided by `Xamarin.NineOldAndroids` the Xamarin implementation doesn't reference that namespace.

Is there a way to use `TypeForwardedToAttribute`, `ClassLoader` overrides etc to modify this without recompiling Forms or NOA? Or possibly inject a using directive into the Xamarin assembly, or change the namespace mappings of NOA without recompiling.. I don't think any of those are possible but I thought I'd ask.

I have tried to change the `java.system.class.loader` but it doesn't seem to be used, everything appears to go through `JNIEnv.FindClass` which might use `PathClassLoader` directly? I'm not really sure.

Comment: I don't see any reason to support pre-API 14. Anyways, I don't think it is possible to typeforward NineOldAndroids to something that does not use that library. I am pretty sure you will hit walls when using Maps too. A good alternative, although not so much UI related apart from having a nice binding engine, would be MvvmCross. You could use its CrossUI, which is built on the idea of MonoTouch.Dialog. However, you won't be able to define UI in PCL's.

Comment: The reason I want to support pre 14 is a significant portion of our userbase are in developing countries, and own very cheap devices which still run API 10 or even 8.

Comment: Then drop the idea about using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Not until I've done due diligence on it.

Comment: Consider adding the C# tag as well. Anyways, good luck hope you find something useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms supports Android 4.0(API 14) or higher, [Check it out](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm aware that Xamarin bills it as API 14 and above, however it is technically able to work if all the referenced classes are implemented with Android Support Libraries or by other means. Which is what I'm exploring with this question.

Comment: I have worked on ListView animation by using https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations java binding project, you can achieve this by Dependency services.